# Tangent Plane w/ a Minus Sign?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The tangent plane to a surface $u = f(x,y)$ is [given by](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TangentPlane.html)

$$z = f(x_0,y_0) + \tfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}|_{(x_0,y_0)}(x-x_0)+\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}|_{(x_0,y_0)}(y-y_0).$$

So why does a book I'm reading say that the tangent plane at a point $(x,y,u)$ on the surface $u = f(x,y)$ has the equation

$$z = \tfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}|_{(x_0,y_0)}(x-x_0)+\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}|_{(x_0,y_0)}(y-y_0) - f(x_0,y_0) = \alpha x + \beta y - u ?$$

How does it all of a sudden become *minus* $f(x_0,y_0)$?

(The motivation is viewing the Legendre transformation as a means to switch from point coordinates $(x,y,u)$ to line coordinates $(\alpha, \beta,u) = (\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial x},\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial y},u)$ by just viewing the surface as made up from tangent lines instead of points, please factor that into your answer if you can, thanks).

Comment: Does the book use this definition including the minus sign later on? If not, I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't respond to your question about the Legendre transform, but the formula you found in your textbook is incorrect as written. The point $(x_0,y_0,f(x_0,y_0))$ should lie on the tangent plane, but letting $x=x_0$ and $y=y_0$ in the equation you gave yields $z=-f(x_0,y_0)$.